# have any example of dotnetnuke plugin?

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

i am new in plugin development for asp.net, so i am using DotNetNuke open source for developing, please send me any link documentation or send me any sample plugin documentation links. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

here is good examples for dotnetnuke plugin.

http://www.dnncreative.com/Default.aspx
http://www.dnnhero.com/
http://www.deitel.com/ResourceCenters/Software/DotNetNukeDNN/DotNetNukeTutorials/tabid/1445/Default.aspx

Arun Kumar

Answer (score 0):

I have a video series for a Task Manager module that you should check out, along with a number of entries in the DotNetNuke Wiki on how to setup your development environment

http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/Module-Development.aspx

Another example module is http://dnnsimplearticle.codeplex.com